# Setting up CruiseControl.Net to always check for modifications

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

So I imagine this is a pretty simple problem, but I can't find anything about it.

I've set up CruiseControl.Net to check my svn repository for any changes every 30 seconds, and if there are any changes, build them using NAnt.

Everything works great - but only if I have the CruiseControl.Net console running at all time on the server. If I close the console, it won't check for changes and build them. I've checked the [wiki](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki) for a way to set up continuous monitoring, but I can't find anything

Does the console always need to be running in order to detect changes, or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to run CCNET: As console application or as windows service. You're looking for windows service mode.

[Here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/The+Server+Service+Application) is a tutorial on "Installing CCService". Be aware that this documentation is outdated. But it should give you an impression.

Installing CCNET as a windows service is an option during CCNET installation so this is the easiest way to get it up and running.